# Avoid While or Cursor with MS SQL Server and Terdata?

Tags: sql, while-loop, cursor, teradata

I have a very large table that we recently added two columns to for a new report. The problem is that we have to go back and pull the original data from Teradata to update each current column. It isn't too bad when writing up a while statement or cursor but the performance and speed of the job is extremely slow. I've found myself here once before and am looking to avoid this now.

Are there any recommendations to expedite the pull from Teradata and updating our local tables?

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY var4) AS ROW, * INTO #updateData FROM TBL_UPDATE_ME
WHERE var4 IS NOT NULL AND col1 IS NULL

DECLARE @TERADATA table (col1 VARCHAR(10) , col2 NVARCHAR(10))

DECLARE
@QUERY VARCHAR(MAX),
@row int = 1,
@DATE nvarchar(10),
@TIME NVARCHAR(8),
@code NVARCHAR(8),
@var3 NVARCHAR(8),
@var4 NVARCHAR(20),
@var2 NVARCHAR(10)

while @row <= (select MAX(row) from #updatedata)
begin

    SELECT @DATE = (SELECT date FROM #updatedata where ROW = @row)
    SELECT @TIME = (SELECT time FROM #updatedata where ROW = @row)
    SELECT @code = (SELECT code FROM #updatedata where ROW = @row)
    SELECT @var3 = (SELECT var3 FROM #updatedata where ROW = @row)
    SELECT @var4 = (SELECT var4 FROM #updatedata where ROW = @row)
    SELECT @var2 = (SELECT var2 FROM #updatedata where ROW = @row)


    SET @QUERY = 
    '
        SELECT col1, col2
        FROM OPENQUERY (AAAAAAA_TERADATA,''
        SELECT
        TRIM(LEADING '''' '''' FROM (TRIM (TRAILING '''' '''' FROM a.col1))) AS col1,
        TRIM(LEADING '''' '''' FROM (TRIM (TRAILING '''' '''' FROM a.col2))) AS col2
        FROM WWWWWW.WWWWWW as a
        left join TTTTT.TTTTas b
        on a.var1 = b.var1
        WHERE
        (
            B.var4 = '''''+@var4+'''''
            AND B.var2 = '''''+@var2+'''''
            AND B.var3 = '''''+@var3+'''''
            AND B.code = '''''+@code+'''''
            AND B.time = '''''+@TIME+'''''
            AND B.date = '''''+@DATE+'''''
        )

        '')
    '
    INSERT INTO @TERADATA
    EXEC(@QUERY)

set @row = @row + 1
end

update a
set a.col1 = b.col1 , a.col2 = b.col2
from TBL_UPDATE_ME as a, @TERADATA as b

drop table #updateData
```

Comment: Of course this is slow, you submit one remote Select for each row (plus 6 Selects to set the variables), this is worst case in every DBMS. I don't see any reason why you can't rewrite it a a single statement?

Comment: dnoeth - I see where the improvement can come with the variables but don't have the strong SQL background to get away from the while. Any idea?

Comment: If it's a large number of rows then either get all rows from Teradata in a single Select (unless this is a much larger table) or Insert/Select (or load) the `#updateData` rows into a temp table in Teradata and join...